# NSURLConnection on device changes protocol from https to http

Tags: iphone, nsurlconnection

I'm not sure what to do. I have an app that is required to log into a website over a secure connection. Our development environment uses a subdomain and a self signed certificate. So I did a search and found the self signed certificate fix, i.e. `- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge` and `- (BOOL)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace:(NSURLProtectionSpace *)protectionSpace` which works perfectly when running the app in the simulator. However, when I run the app on a device, I fall into the `- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection
  didFailWithError:(NSError *)error` method. In this method I log the URL and I see it is not what I set in my NSMuatableURLRequest.

My NSMuatableURLRequest: https://sub.domain.com/app/login/

Connection Error URL as logged: http://www.sub.domain.com/app/login

Is there a workaround? Does this only happen for self signed certificates?

Comment: you need to have your self signed certificate.

Comment: We do, and we have it auto accept the certificate but still on the device it fails.